# Как повесить параметр на кнопку и передать этот параметр в Controller Spring

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Есть кнопка "Январь" со значением "Month.JANUARY" (это значение из Enum).

При нажатии на "Январь", нужно передать значение Month.JANUARY в контроллер

```java
@GetMapping("/month")
public String month(Model model, Month month) {
    List<String> monthList = new EnMonth().dOf(month);
    model.addAttribute("months", monthList);
    return "month";
}
```

то есть параметр Month month должен получить значение кнопки Month.JANUARY.

Кнопка:

```html
<input id="month" type="submit" value="Month.JANUARY" name="Январь"
    class="btn btn-success finish" data-loading-text="Sent!"/>
```

Не пойму, как передать значение в контроллер? Может нужен Post запрос?

Comment: В кнопке `value` имеет тип `String`. Думаю, вам нужно в контроллере преобразовать `String` в `enum`. Или работать со строками

Comment: А что должно происходить после нажатия ?

Comment: @НиколайГнап после нажатия параметр Month.JANUARY отправляется в контроллер, параметр вставляется сюда new EnMonth().dOf(month); и уже в браузере происходит отображение списка monthList - а это числа от 1 до 31

Comment: Я так понял, что без js не обойтись